# Shebang in Node for windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently learning Node.JS on my windows machine.  I've got my path set up and I've done quite a bit of development already (running all my scripts in cygwin).  Finally, it's time for me to run these directly instead of calling 'node --harmony script.js'.  The tutorial I'm using says to attach

`#!usr/bin/env node --harmony`

at the top of the file. Of course, this doesn't exactly work. My path variable says that the node program itself is in:

`D:\NodeJS\`

I've tried several different ways to use the Shebang to no avail. Every time I run the script, it announces:

`./dbcli.js: line 1: #!D:/NodeJS/: no such file or directory`

Anyone know how this is supposed to be used? Here's the code so far:

```js
#!d:/NodeJS/node --harmony

const
request = require("request"),
options = {
    method: process.argv[2] || 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:5984/' + (process.argv[3] || '')
};

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        throw Error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(res.statusCode, JSON.parse(body));
    }
});
```

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12747/63707 - No idea if it works under Cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer and it turned out to be a bizarre one. Since I was developing in Visual Studio, the files were encoded as UTF-8 With BOM.  As a result, it was getting a whole lot of nonsense in the file while attempting to run it directly.

The above code :

```js
#!d:/NodeJS/node --harmony

const
request = require("request"),
options = {
    method: process.argv[2] || 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:5984/' + (process.argv[3] || '')
};

request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        throw Error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(res.statusCode, JSON.parse(body));
    }
});
```

was exactly what I needed, but, since it was incorrectly encoded, it never worked. For the time being, I'm editing all scripts in Visual Studio and, for the ones I want to run directly, I'll open Notepad++ and switch over the encoding (until I find a better way).

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I get this error: `'myTool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`